# Bar chart Achartengine have text above the bar

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I would like to have text above the bars of my bar chart, can anyone tell me to do it?

Like in this picture :

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution :

```
// add an annotation for each bar
series.addAnnotation("text", x, y);
```